# Facebook login web

Tags: javascript, facebook, web, authentication

I want to login into my website using facebook.
There is following example at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/web. But if I enter it into a html-file (with changing the app-ID of course) it just does nothing and I don't know why. Also in the web console I cannot see anything.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Facebook Login JavaScript Example</title>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<body>

<script>
  // This is called with the results from from FB.getLoginStatus().
  function statusChangeCallback(response) {
    console.log('statusChangeCallback');
    console.log(response);
    // The response object is returned with a status field that lets the
    // app know the current login status of the person.
    // Full docs on the response object can be found in the documentation
    // for FB.getLoginStatus().
    if (response.status === 'connected') {
      // Logged into your app and Facebook.
      testAPI();
    } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
      // The person is logged into Facebook, but not your app.
      document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = 'Please log ' +
        'into this app.';
    } else {
      // The person is not logged into Facebook, so we're not sure if
      // they are logged into this app or not.
      document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = 'Please log ' +
        'into Facebook.';
    }
  }

  // This function is called when someone finishes with the Login
  // Button.  See the onlogin handler attached to it in the sample
  // code below.
  function checkLoginState() {
    FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
      statusChangeCallback(response);
    });
  }

  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
  FB.init({
    appId      : '1234567890',
    cookie     : true,  // enable cookies to allow the server to access 
                        // the session
    xfbml      : true,  // parse social plugins on this page
    version    : 'v2.3' // use version 2.3
  });

  // Now that we've initialized the JavaScript SDK, we call 
  // FB.getLoginStatus().  This function gets the state of the
  // person visiting this page and can return one of three states to
  // the callback you provide.  They can be:
  //
  // 1. Logged into your app ('connected')
  // 2. Logged into Facebook, but not your app ('not_authorized')
  // 3. Not logged into Facebook and can't tell if they are logged into
  //    your app or not.
  //
  // These three cases are handled in the callback function.

  FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
    statusChangeCallback(response);
  });

  };

  // Load the SDK asynchronously
  (function(d, s, id) {
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
    js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
  }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

  // Here we run a very simple test of the Graph API after login is
  // successful.  See statusChangeCallback() for when this call is made.
  function testAPI() {

    console.log('Welcome!  Fetching your information.... ');
    FB.api('/me', function(response) {
      console.log('Successful login for: ' + response.name);
      document.getElementById('status').innerHTML =
        'Thanks for logging in, ' + response.name + '!';
    });
  }
</script>

<!--
  Below we include the Login Button social plugin. This button uses
  the JavaScript SDK to present a graphical Login button that triggers
  the FB.login() function when clicked.
-->

<fb:login-button scope="public_profile,email" onlogin="checkLoginState();">
</fb:login-button>

<div id="status">
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Could someone help me out and get this first example work? 
Thanks in advance.

Best regards

Comment: have you published your app in your fb developper parameter? and put your callback url too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:
Go to facebook developper page.
On settings tab, add your app domains into field "app domain" (it is your app url) after that, you have to wait some minutes and go to "status and review" and toggle your app on public mode. The effect appear after some minutes (20 - 30 minutes) and try again.

Comment: So do I understand that right, that it is not possible to first explore it on my local maschine via localhost?

Comment: yes put your localhost url into app domain filed in Fb develloper page

Comment: Yaaaay - you saved my life :D
Thank you so much. Don't know, why Facebook isn't providing this information anywhere.

Comment: @LilK3ks: Not having the app domain configured correctly should have given you an error in the browser console, the JS SDK should have complained about that.

Answer (score -2):

Your appid is 1234567890. Is it a coincidence or you just made it up? If it is the latter, go to developers.facebook.com to set up your app. Otherwise, the FB.getLoginStatus will get exception and will not execute statusChangeCallback.

Comment: I don't want to show my real app id here.
So my real app id is standing right in there and 1234567890 is just made up.